# Inverting a linear system of inequalities

Tags: inequalities, linear-matrix-inequalities

Suppose I have a set of inequalities $l \leq Ax \leq r$ for vectors $l,r$ and matrix $A$. I am trying to bound $x$ using a function of $l,r: f(l) \leq x \leq g(r)$ for some $f,g$. When can we invert this system? Alternatively, I want a change of basis from $x$ to an orthogonal basis $x'$ such that $f(l) \leq x' \leq g(r)$.

**Concrete example**:

I have $6$ integral variables, $m,z,p, m',z',p'$. I have a set of three inequalities:

$$m\leq m' \leq p+m$$
$$m \leq m'-z' \leq p+m$$
$$2p+2m+z \leq 2m'+p'\leq 2p+2m+z$$

Or in matrix format

$
\begin{bmatrix}
m  \\
m \\
2m+2p+z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\leq
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m'\\
z'\\
p'\\
\end{bmatrix}
\leq 
\begin{bmatrix}
m+p\\
m+p\\
2m+2p+z\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

I am trying to solve this system to bound $m',z',p'$ **individually** in terms of $m,z,p$. Meaning, I want an expression as:
$
{\bf f}(m,z,p)\leq \begin{bmatrix}
m' \\
z' \\
p' \\
\end{bmatrix}\leq {\bf g}(m,z,p)
$

Alternatively, I want a change of basis from $m',z',p'$ to an **orthogonal** basis $r,s,t$ such that
$
{\bf f}(m,z,p)\leq \begin{bmatrix}
r \\
s \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix}\leq {\bf g}(m,z,p)
$

Comment: I don't think this is possible: the bounds on $m'$ will depend on $z'$ and $p'$, so you can not hope to obtain an equality of the form $f(m,z,p)\leq m'\leq g(m,z,p)$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker This doesn't rule out that a linear transormation would give such set right? For example, setting $r=m'+z', s=z'+p', t=..$ leading to such set.

Comment: but you want not just any linear transformation, but an orthogonal transformation, right? that will not work in general.

Comment: In "When can we invert this system?", what do you mean by "when"? Do you want a necessary and sufficient condition? If so, in what terms do you want the condition on $A,l,r$ to be stated?

Comment: Also, looking at your $f(l) \le x \le g(r)$, it seems that you want the lower bound on $x$ to depend only on $l$, and the upper bound on $x$ to depend only on $r$. On the other hand, in your "Concrete example", these "depend only on" conditions do not seem to hold. ??

Comment: It's more complicated than what you state (just consider $A=-I$ to see that the bounds can not be like you want them in your initial statement).